# Ansible playbook: create a many username but i have a problem

Tags: ubuntu, ansible

```
- name: Create a many dev and ops account in managed 1
  hosts: pod-jesayafernando9-managed1
  become: true
  tasks:
         - name: Create dev[1-50] in managed 1
           ansible.builtin.user:
                        name: "{{item}}"
                        password: adinusa88
                        state: present
           loop: dev[1:50]

         - name: Create ops[1-50] in managed 1
           ansible.builtin.user:
                        name: "{{item}}"
                        password: adinusa88
                        state: present
           loop: ops[1:50]
- name: Create a many dev and ops account in managed 2
  hosts: pod-jesayafernando9-managed2
  become: true
  tasks:
          - name: Create dev[51-100] in managed 2
            ansible.builtin.user:
                        name: "{{item}}"
                        password: adinusa88
                        state: present
            loop: dev[51:100]

          - name: Create ops[51-100] in managed 2
            ansible.builtin.user:
                        name: "{{item}}"
                        password: adinusa88
                        state: present
            loop: ops[51:100]
```

How to make username dev1...dev100 or ops1...ops100?
I try using with_squence but when it reaches 10 an alphabet instead of numbers come out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with_sequence works correctly using the following way, I created a small example on my computer from ops1 to ops50. The unique issue I see there is the performance, its kinda slow.

```
---
- hosts: dev
  tasks:
    - name: create users
      user:
        name: ops{{item}}
        password: "{{'test' | password_hash('sha512')}}"
        state: present
      with_sequence: start=1 end=50
```

As official ansible documentation says there: [ANSIBLE WITH_SEQUENCE DOC](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#with-sequence)
with_sequence is replaced with loop on this way:

```
---
- hosts: dev
  tasks:
    - name: create users
      user:
        name: ops{{item}}
        password: "{{'test' | password_hash('sha512')}}"
        state: present
      loop: "{{range(1,50)| list}}"
```

I would recommend using this one because its what ansible official documentation says,